# SQL Views (If Statement)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two different views which have the same exact columns, but different data. They are called depending on a value of a key.

Now, instead of having my sql functions with an if statement, can i do that somewhere centralized. Like a new view with an IF statement? (I know this is not possible)

**UPDATE**

Based on the comments below, i need to create a sql table function, can you help me with the code below?

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetCorrectData ( @id INT )
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    ( 

    SELECT    *       FROM      view1
    -- how to add the if here for view 2?
    --if @id=10 then view1 else view2
    )
```

Thanks

Comment: SQL doesn't support passing of keys into views.  Several databases support table-valued functions which basically have this functionality.

Comment: So a table valued function that does that would work?

Comment: That would meet the requirements of what you want to do.

Comment: Yep it looks like table value function would work for you.

Comment: You are almost there. `if @id=10 select * from view1 else select * from view2`

Comment: I get incorrect syntax near If. Expecting '(', select or WITH error....

Comment: I think i need to create a table variable in the function and insert the data in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might look at this:

Both views return two columns of string-type.

This *inline/ad-hoc* approach should be faster as *procedural* approaches with `IF`. The inline function is predictable, the optimizier will be able to use indexes and statistics.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.Test1 AS
SELECT COLUMN_NAME,TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.Test2 AS
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE';
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyFunc(@key INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
SELECT * FROM dbo.Test1 WHERE @Key=1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM dbo.Test2 WHERE @Key=2;
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.MyFunc(1); --try 2 as well
GO

DROP FUNCTION dbo.MyFunc;
DROP VIEW dbo.Test2;
DROP VIEW dbo.Test1;
```

Comment: this is very interesting, i will try this too.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to create a new view , for instance ,

```
CREATE VIEW view3 AS
SELECT a.*, 'view_1' as view_type
FROM view1 a
UNION ALL
SELECT b.*, 'view_2' as view_type
FROM view2 b
```

Then you can query data from a particular view by `SELECT * from view3 WHERE view_type ='view_1'`.

Comment: the sizes of the views are really big, this is not an option

Comment: @Shnugo  : I'd give it a try. Regardless of table size, decent optimizer would do predicate pushing and generate multiple execution plans which will be the same as if each view is  queried separately.